# How to declare variable type as generic?

Tags: delphi

I am creating a double linked list class and I am trying to change the type of data that the list is storing when the object is created.

```
TItem = record
  value: string;
  address, prev, next: integer;
end;

TDoubleLinkedList = class
private
  length, head, tail: integer;
  data: array of TItem;
public
  constructor Create;
  procedure add(value: string);
  function get(address: integer): string;
  property Values[address: integer]: string read get; default;
end;
```

Is there any way to declare TItem.value as having a variable type than can be changed when the object is created? I want to be able to (in a separate unit) call something analogous to array of type and have TItem.value be that type.

Comment: `TItem<T> = record
    value: T;
    address, prev, next: integer;
  end;`?

Comment: Which version of Delphi are you using?

Comment: Not sure this q deserves the downvotes it's received, so I hope the OP is not put off.

Comment: More generic list types: https://github.com/delphidabbler/delphi-coll-xe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I want to be able to (in a separate unit) call something analogous to array of type and have TItem.value be that type.

Depending on your real needs, you may choose from:

- [Generics](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Overview_of_Generics) are good for cases, when all elements in the list will have the same type. In fact there are some ready to use list implementations in standard library in [System.Generics.Collections](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Generics.Collections)
- [Variant](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Variant_Types_(Delphi)) is nice when you need dynamic behaviour, as in JS, when the same variable can be treated as integer or string in different areas in your code
- [TValue](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Rtti.TValue) allows you to store elements with different types, but is type safe, i.e. once defined, type does not change. Two good articles: [Introduction to TValue](http://robstechcorner.blogspot.com/2009/09/introduction-to-tvalue.html), [TValue in Depth](http://robstechcorner.blogspot.com/2009/09/tvalue-in-depth.html)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to declare TItem.value as having a variable type that can be changed when the object is created?

Make your record and class using **generics**, so the type of `data[x].value` is bound to the type `T` of the `TDoubleLinkedList`.

```
type
  TItem<T> = record
    value: T;
    address, prev, next: integer;
  end;

  TDoubleLinkedList<T> = class
  private
    length, head, tail: integer;
    data: array of TItem<T>;
  public
    constructor Create;
    procedure add(value: T);
    function get(address: integer): T;
    property Values[address: integer]: T read get; default;
  end;
```

Example usage:

```
var
  dll_int: TDoubleLinkedList<integer>;
  dll_string: TDoubleLinkedList<string>;
begin
  dll_int := TDoubleLinkedList<integer>.Create;
  try
    dll_int.add(42);
    writeln(dll_int.get(0)); // returns 42
  finally
    dll_int.Free;
  end;

  dll_string := TDoubleLinkedList<string>.Create;
  try
    dll_string.add('Test');
    writeln(dll_string.get(0)); // returns 'Test'
  finally
    dll_string.Free;
  end;

end.
```